# OpenCPU markdown document with arguments

Tags: r, r-markdown, opencpu

I would like to produce reproducible markdown documents using OpenCPU that accepts arguments. Similar to the basic example here:

curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/knitr/examples/knitr-minimal.Rmd -d "format=html"

I would like to include variables in the Rmarkdown document that would be specified in the call, eg:

curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/knitr/examples/knitr-minimal.Rmd -d "format=html&variable1=foo&variable2=bar"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a way with (say) `rmarkdown::render` to identify a template `.Rmd` file, fields to replace, and values to put in those fields? I don't know of an already-defined method, so I think your best bet is to create a function that takes the `.Rmd` file as a template and key-name variables, replaces them and compiles it. Not too hard, but I haven't seen an automatic way to do it.

Comment: Though it hasn't been updated in over two years, the package [whiskers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/whisker/index.html) might be a start, depending on the types of variables.